# Carrierwave Discards Meta Data On Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

My Uploader File

```
# encoding: utf-8

class EngagementUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::Processing::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::ImageOptimizer

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted: #{model.name.to_s.underscore}
  def store_dir
    "#{model.class.to_s.pluralize.parameterize}/#{model.id}/"
  end

  process :optimize => [{ quality: 90 }]

  #process :watermark

  #process :blur => [0, 8]

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end
  # version :large do
  #   process :resize_to_fill => [512, 512]
  # end
  # version :medium do
  #   process :resize_to_fill => [128, 128]
  # end
  # version :small do
  #   process :resize_to_fill => [48, 48]
  # end
  # version :tiny do
  #   process :resize_to_fill => [32, 32]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

  def filename
    if original_filename
      "post-#{secure_token(16)}.#{file.extension}"
    end
  end

  protected
  def secure_token(length=16)
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
  end

  # def watermark
  #   manipulate! do |img|
  #     logo = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/watermark.png").first
  #     img = img.composite(logo, Magick::SouthEastGravity, 15, 15, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
  #   end
  # end

end
```

I am uploading a `360` image and when i try to read the meta from the uploade file everything is lost. Is there a way to preserve it on upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A casual search returns the Gem [Carrierwave-meta](https://github.com/gzigzigzeo/carrierwave-meta). Basically, add to your gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave-meta'
```

and then run `bundle install`. Then add the `store_meta` option to your uploader:

```
class TestUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::Meta

  process :store_meta => [{md5sum: true}]
  version :version do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
    process :store_meta
  end
end

file = File.open('test.jpg') # JPEG 500x300, 20000 bytes
uploader = TestUploader.new
uploader.store!(file)

uploader.width        # 500
uploader.height       # 300
uploader.image_size   # [500, 300]
```

Of course, you will need to make sure your model can store the values:

```
class TestModel
  attr_accessor :image_width
  attr_accessor :image_height
  attr_accessor :image_image_size
  attr_accessor :image_content_type
  attr_accessor :image_file_size
  attr_accessor :image_md5sum

  attr_accessor :image_version_width
  attr_accessor :image_version_height
  attr_accessor :image_version_image_size
  attr_accessor :image_version_content_type
  attr_accessor :image_version_file_size
  attr_accessor :image_version_md5sum
end
```

Comment: i do not need the meta data itself. it has to embedded at meta tags inside the Image for it to be recognized by facebook.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I really couldn't tell you then.